# Is in C# List something like vector.reserve(n) in C++

Tags: c#, c++, list, using, stdvector

When adding a lot of elements in `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` it is running slow because when nums increases capacity it must copy all elements.
In C++ this is fixed with `vector.reserve(n)`. How can i do that in C#?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
list.Capacity = n;
```

or you can set initial capacity via the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = new List<int>(n);
```

Comment: Can also be specified via the constructor