# Most performant way to filter a huge List in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, caching

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application that is hooked up to a SQL Server DB via Entity Framework. One of the main tasks of this application is to allow users to quickly search and filter a huge database table that holds archive values.

The table structure is quite simple: Timestamp (DateTime), StationId (int), DatapointId (int), Value (double). This table holds somewhat between 10 to 100 million rows. I optimized the DB table with a covering index etc., but the user experience was still quite laggy when filtering by DatapointId, StationId, Time and Skipping and Taking only the portion I want to show on the page.

So I tried a different approach: as our server has a lot of RAM, I thought that we could simply load the whole archive table into a `List<ArchiveRow>` when the web app starts up, then simply get the data directly from this List instead of doing a round-trip to the database. This works quite well, it takes about 9 seconds to load the whole archive table (with currently about 10 million entries) into the List. The `ArchiveRow` is a simple object that looks like this:

```
public class ArchiveResponse {
    public  int Length { get; set; }
    public int numShown { get; set; }
    public  int numFound { get; set; }
    public  int numTotal { get; set; }
    public  List<ArchiveRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

and accordingly:

```
public class ArchiveRow {
    public  int s { get; set; }
    public  int d { get; set; }
    public  DateTime t { get; set; }
    public  double v { get; set; }
}
```

When I now try to get the desired data from the List with a Linq query, it is already faster the querying the DB, but it is still quite slow when filtering by multiple criteria. For example, when I filter by one StationId and 12 DatapointIds, it takes about 5 seconds to retrieve a window of 25 rows. I already switched from filtering with `Where` to using joins, but I think there is still room for improvement. Are there maybe better ways to implement such a caching mechanism while keeping memory consumption as low as possible? Are there other collection types that are better suited for this purpose?

So here is the code that filters and fetches the relevant data from the ArchiveCache list:

```
// Total number of entries in archive cache
var numTotal = ArchiveCache.Count();

// Initial Linq query
ParallelQuery<ArchiveCacheValue> query = ArchiveCache.AsParallel();

// The request may contain StationIds that the user is interested in,
// so here's the filtering by StationIds with a join:
if (request.StationIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = from a in ArchiveCache.AsParallel()
             join b in request.StationIds.AsParallel()
             on a.StationId equals b
             select a;
}

// The request may contain DatapointIds that the user is interested in,
// so here's the filtering by DatapointIds with a join:
if (request.DatapointIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = from a in query.AsParallel()
             join b in request.DatapointIds.AsParallel()
             on a.DataPointId equals b
             select a;
}

// Number of matching entries after filtering and before windowing
int numFound = query.Count();

// Pagination: Select only the current window that needs to be shown on the page
var result = query.Skip(request.Start == 0 ? 0 : request.Start - 1).Take(request.Length);

// Number of entries on the current page that will be shown
int numShown = result.Count();

// Build a response object, serialize it to Json and return to client
// Note: The projection with the Rows is not a bottleneck, it is only done to
// shorten 'StationId' to 's' etc. At this point there are only 25 to 50 rows,
// so that is no problem and happens in way less than 1 ms
ArchiveResponse myResponse = new ArchiveResponse();
myResponse.Length = request.Length;
myResponse.numShown = numShown;
myResponse.numFound = numFound;
myResponse.numTotal = numTotal;
myResponse.Rows = result.Select(x => new archRow() { s = x.StationId, d = x.DataPointId, t = x.DateValue, v = x.Value }).ToList();

return JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(myResponse);
```

Some more details: the number of stations is usually something between 5 to 50, rarely more than 50. The number of datapoints is <7000. The web application is set to 64 bit with `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` set in the web.config.

I'm really looking forward for further improvements and recommendations. Maybe there's a completely different approach based on arrays or similar, that performs way better *without* linq?

Comment: Perhaps edit and add details of the table design & the SQL Query that was performing poorly so people can suggest possible improvements, as you have described it one would expect it to be perfectly performant.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, I know where you're heading, but I did not describe the DB part on purpose as I want to explicitely improve this caching mechanism.

Comment: I would give the underlying query parameters some sort of identifier or hash so you can near-field cache the data-set from filtering, your windowing will then just re-use it (don't include the paging info in the identifier). You can then cache `query.Count()` which does a full iteration each time. The challenge is the variance of filtering parameters and the likelihood the same set will re-visit (for the next page). If the users tend to get multiple pages, consider returning batches of pages instead.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, interesting idea... I will consider that.

Comment: LINQ will use the ``IEnumberable<T>`` interface to work on the list of entries. With 10 million entries I imagine this might make a difference compared to using ``List<T>``. It may be worth implementing a subset of LINQ extension methods for ``List<T>``, and checking if this would improve performance.

Comment: Only other general advice I have is to walk away from LINQ / `IQueryable` and try to iterate only once manually. You have things like `Parallel.ForEach` that can help here.

Comment: @Adam: Parallel.ForEach changes everything... please see my comment on Evk's answer.

Comment: @Robert Nice one. Yeah when you get to this stage and need perf, you almost always have to go custom (unless there is a clanger in the code somewhere, but that is unlikely). Using highly-specific lookups, data structures, or ordering of data tends to be where the wins are. Then it's just a case of keeping a lid on memory usage, GC pressure, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust your storage to this specific query type. First, create dictionaries from your in-memory archive:

```
ArchiveCacheByDatapoint = ArchiveCache.GroupBy(c => c.DataPointId)
            .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.ToList());
ArchiveCacheByStation = ArchiveCache.GroupBy(c => c.StationId)
            .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.ToList());
```

Then use those dictionaries in your query:

```
bool hasStations = request.StationIds.Length > 0;
bool hasDatapoints = request.DatapointIds.Length > 0;            
int numFound = 0;
List<ArchiveCacheValue> result;
if (hasDatapoints && hasStations) {
    // special case - filter by both
    result = new List<ArchiveCacheValue>();
    // store station filter in hash set
    var stationsFilter = new HashSet<int>(request.StationIds);
    // first filter by datapoints, because you have more different datapoints than stations
    foreach (var datapointId in request.DatapointIds.OrderBy(c => c)) {                    
        foreach (var item in ArchiveCacheByDatapoint[datapointId]) {                        
            if (stationsFilter.Contains(item.StationId)) {
                // both datapoint and station matches filter - found item
                numFound++;
                if (numFound >= request.Start && result.Count < request.Length) {
                    // add to result list if matches paging criteria
                    result.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (hasDatapoints) {                
    var query = Enumerable.Empty<ArchiveCacheValue>();                
    foreach (var datapoint in request.DatapointIds.OrderBy(c => c))
    {
        var list = ArchiveCacheByDatapoint[datapoint];
        numFound += list.Count;
        query = query.Concat(list);
    }
    // execute query just once
    result = query.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length).ToList();
}
else if (hasStations) {                
    var query = Enumerable.Empty<ArchiveCacheValue>();
    foreach (var station in request.StationIds.OrderBy(c => c))
    {
        var list = ArchiveCacheByStation[station];
        numFound += list.Count;
        query = query.Concat(list);
    }
    // execute query just once
    result = query.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length).ToList();
}
else {
    // no need to do Count()
    numFound = ArchiveCache.Count;
    // no need to Skip\Take here really, ArchiveCache is list\array
    // so you can use indexes which will be faster
    result = ArchiveCache.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length).ToList();
}

// Number of entries on the current page that will be shown
int numShown = result.Count;
```

I've measured it and on my machine it runs in 1ms (sometimes up to 10ms) for all types of queries I tried (by sections only, by datapoints only, by both sections and datapoints), for 100 million items.

Comment: I've thought about dictionaries, too... They are efficient and fast, but the come at a price as they increase memory consumption a lot. Maybe I can use this mechanism as some kind of "premium" cache for only the most recent data (which gets requested most).

Comment: @Robert not really. Items from ArchiveCache are not copied to dictionary. For 10 millions of items you might expect around 40MB additional memory taken by dictionary, so 80MB total for 2 dictionaries, which is not much as for me. You can measure yourself by calling `GC.GetTotalMemory()` before and after creating dictionary and comparing results. And for that 80MB you will save quite a lot of CPU resources, because your queries will run at least 10 times faster (maybe even 100 times). Plus good user experience.

Comment: Oh... ok! That changes alot, I did not measure it yet. You're right, the magic is done by reference, of course. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @Robert please write here after you try, I wonder if my assumptions about this are correct :)

Comment: I will! I'm out of time atm, but I will get back here next week. BTW: I did a quick test without linq and with Parallel.ForEach building my own filtering mechanism, as Adam pointed out... this is a MASSIVE improvement! I've just tested with a 70 million rows dataset with 60 stations, a complete roundtrip from browser to server and back to browser now takes only 9ms - fast enough for search-as-you-type! I will definitely see Linq with different eyes from now on... at least for these huge amounts of data.

Comment: @Robert yes I tested dictionaries out of curiosity, with 10 milltion of items on my machine takes about 50ms to perform a query (with 50 stations and 7000 datapoints).

Comment: But Adam as I understand suggests to cache some results, so his solution can be combined with this one.

Comment: I've added more optimizations, now in all cases in runs in less than 10ms (most often just 1ms) even for 100 million items.

Answer (score 3):

I would at least store those values in an `array` or `vector` of `struct ArchiveRow` to make sure all data is in contiguous memory. This way you will greatly benefit from [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Spatial_and_temporal_locality_usage) (i.e. use the L1 cache efficiently). And you also avoid the overhead of a `list` (pointers/references). (Update: I did a quick lookup of `C# List`. Looks like `List` is the same as `C++ vector` (i.e. an array), and `C# LinkedList` is the same as `C++ list`.. a bit confusing - iow, no pointer overhead here for the `C# List<>`)

Try to make the struct as small as possible. Use `uint32` or even `uint16` where possible, maybe 32 bit for the `datetime` and maybe even `float` instead of `double` (depending on your values). Also put the widest values first in your struct (for better alignment).

Even the brute force approach (scanning the whole array, a few 100MB of contiguous memory) should finish in well under 1 second.

To optimize further you can sort the data (or better, retrieve it sorted from the database) which will allow you to do a binary search, and also keep the values for the resultset close together. For example: sort on `StationId`, `DataPointId`.

If the data gets bigger, you could store the same structure on disk (in a binary file) and access it via memory mapping.

Also, you only have to scan for the first 25 items. You could then store the last checked position (for that session / query), and when the next page is asked, start from there for the next 25 items. This will also save on memory which would be needed to store the full resultset.

If the number of stations is small, and the data is sorted on `StationId`, you could also keep a small list or jump table (while importing) with the starting position of each `StationId` and directly jump to there to scan for datapoints of that station.

---

> it takes about 9 seconds to load the whole archive table (with
>   currently about 10 million entries) into the List.

Just in case you didn't do this already, make sure to set an initial [Capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118111/is-in-c-sharp-list-something-like-vector-reserven-in-c) on the list to avoid multiple reallocations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Evk has some good optimizations, I'd just wanted to point out some very unoptimized things in your original code, maybe removing them would speed it up already:

You do your query in-memory **three times**!

```
// execute query first time
int numFound = query.Count();

var result = query.Skip(request.Start == 0 ? 0 : request.Start - 1).Take(request.Length);

// executing query second time!
int numShown = result.Count();

// executing query third time!    
// result.Select [...] .ToList()
```

You should really do it *once* and then do the counting and pagination on that result.

Answer (score 1):

Another optimization. Using linq `join` in memory is not that efficient.

So instead of joining the `request.StationIds` and `request.DatapointIds` i would create hashsets from them and use simple contains over the hashset. Something like this.

```
if (request.StationIds.Count > 0)
{
    var stationIdSet = new HashSet<int>(request.StationIds);
    query =  (from a in ArchiveCache
             stationIdSet.Contains(a.StationId)
             select a);
               // .AsParallel()
               // .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(...);
}
```

Running it in **sequental** manner for 9m records and 30 station ids, out performed the join with roughly 150 - 250 ms

For the **parallel** version with **MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2**, both (the join and hashset) **were performing worse**.

**NOTE**: AsParallel is putting overhead which for simple operations like those it may not be the best option.